Autostart openbox-autostart
I use the official image of the ubuntu 20.04 for NanoPi M4. It uses LXQT desktop environment. I'm trying to add  a programm to the autolaunch.
I put this into the ~/.config/vnc.desktop:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=VNC
Path=/home/pi/Files
Exec=/home/pi/Files/vnc.sh

And this into the /home/pi/Files/vnc.sh:
x0vncserver -passwordfile /home/pi/.vnc/passwd -display :0

I used chmod +x /home/pi/Files/vnc.sh and sudo chmod +x /home/pi/Files/vnc.sh
But I don't get vnc autostarting after reboot.
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openbox-xdg-autostart --list has this in the output:
[*] VNC
      File: /home/pi/.config/autostart/vnc.desktop
      Executes: /home/pi/Files/vnc.sh

And I see that vnc is in autostart in the system GUI. But it is not starting.
Also I found that it starts when I launch /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openbox-autostart manually in a terminal.
So, it looks for me that openbox-autostart doesnt't autostart itself. How can I fix this?

What is the output of this: desktop-file-validate /home/pi/.config/autostart/vnc.desktop? :)

@Bog no output. I mean, anything is printed into a terminal.
